# How to recover domain that was accidentally canceled?

Tags: domain-name

**Story**
I was in a partnership for an e-commerce web site.  My partner and I decided to part ways(amicably) and he was supposed to transfer the domain to me.  Instead, the domain was cancelled(I'm not sure whether it was his mistake or the web hosting company).

We discovered this almost immediately(the domain was listed as non-transferrable and the domain owner was now the web hosting company) and sent an email to the web hosting company asking for a reversal.

Fast forward two weeks later, they have ignored our emails(and calling was useless).  The status of the domain was then switched to the redemption period.

Now, three weeks later, they replied to my email and said that they "can no longer reverse the domain cancellation request you made.  Since, (sic) the domain is not active anymore."

**Question**
Is there any way for me to get the domain name back without having to wait another month for the redemption period to expire?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the hosting company is not the registrar you can go bug them. However most likely it is in which case you have to deal with the hosting company. Redemption period means that even tho its expired the domain you can still retrieve it from the registrar. I am surprised they are not agreeing to it.

You can go to http://www.icann.org/en/dispute-resolution/#services and list a complaint. Nothing will happen probably but it will be a stain on their record.

You could get a technical lawyer and see if you can send a nasty gram to them. Companies tend to listen when threat of litigation looms over them. However, it probably isn't worth the money and waiting would be a good bet. With the changes ICANN made domains are not being squatted nearly as much anymore since it costs them money now.

Comment: Thanks.  I'd vote up but I don't have the rep right now.